# phpmyadmin, allow access from dynamic ip address

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, phpmyadmin

I have set up a restriction on my /user/phpmyadmin/apache.conf file so that only I can access the phpmyadmin page.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 92.8.xxx.xxx
```

I have a dynamic ip address and everytime my router gets reset I have to change the ip address in the apache.conf file.

Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but it should work:

Go to http://www.no-ip.com/ and register a free domain. Download one of their clients and run it on your pc. It will automatically update your external ip address to that free domain. You can then just put that domain address directly: eg

Allow from example.serve.com

NOTE: the client app does need to run on your pc 24/7 so it can keep updating.